# Digest value not add encrypt.Key in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

encrypt.key not accept digest value and it's accepting the list format value

```
final bytes = utf8.encode(stringKey + plainEmail);
Digest sha256Key = sha256.convert(bytes);


final key = encrypt.Key(sha256Key.bytes);
```

Please check below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN8T1.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Digest.bytes` returns a `List<int>` which, under the hood, is a `Uint8List`. So you need to cast it with:

```
final key = encrypt.Key(sha256Key.bytes as Uint8List);
```

since the constructor of `Key` expects a `Uint8List`.

Any time that you have a `List<int>` that isn't actually a `Uint8List` under the hood (so cannot be cast) you can convert it with:

```
final uInt8List = Uint8List.fromList(anyOldIntList);
```

Comment: If that helped, you should 'accept' the answer. Thanks